# Primeng angular 6 table/turbotable multiple selection on paginated table with filters

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have a table much like the **turbotable** example. I have a global filter on my table and also pagination set up.

With the filter empty `shift + select` works fine because the row indexes match. However once I filter and then do a `shift + select` it doesn't select the expected rows, instead it selects based on the current pages index.

Is there a way to be able to have shift + select on a table with a global filter?

Comment: Apparently, there is a bug at the moment: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicolas Leblancs comment is the answer. Theres an issue raised on [Github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6018)